# Question about "Magnifying" an inequality for big-oh analysis

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Here's an example directly from my numerical analysis text book:

$$
a_n = \frac {n+1}{n^2}
$$

The goal is to find the convergence rate. So we know,

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n+1}{n^2} = 0$

so $\alpha = 0$.

Then it follows if we choose $b_n = \frac 1n$

$|a_n - \alpha| = \frac {n+1}{n^2} \le \frac {n+n}{n^2} = 2\frac{1}{n} = O(\frac 1n)$

I get lost at the point where they do $ \frac {n+n}{n^2} $. what are they doing to magnify the inequality here? I understand it's obvious the inequality still holds, but are they just choosing a polynomial that works out nicely relative to $b_n$ or is there a method to this? Sorry if this is trivial, but the numerical analysis text I have is awful and leaves out key explanations of why they did what they did - assuming it's obvious to the reader.

Thanks!

Comment: $(n+1)/n^2$ is somewhere between $1/n$ and $2/n$. Since we're using $O$-notation, we don't care about the difference between the $1/n$ and $2/n$, as they're proportional. So we go straight to the bigger one, $2/n$. Obviously, $1/n$ is simpler than $(n+1)/n^2$. That's why you'd prefer to say something is $O(1/n)$ than $O((n+1)/n^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To choose the $1/n$, a more intuitive method is to observe that $a_n=\frac{n(1+\frac{1}{n})}{n^2}=\frac{n(1+o(1)}{n^2}=\frac{1+o(1)}{n}\sim\frac{1}{n}$.